# Laravel flush cache with more than one tag

Tags: php, caching, redis, laravel-5

I'm using Redis cache on Laravel 5.2, and I have my keys with 2 tags (basically), the year and the source.

Example:

```
$this->cache->tags(['online', 2016])->put("key1", $value1, 10));
$this->cache->tags(['online', 2016])->put("key2", $value2, 10));
$this->cache->tags(['online', 2017])->put("key3", $value3, 10));
$this->cache->tags(['online', 2017])->put("key4", $value4, 10));

$this->cache->tags(['database', 2016])->put("key5", $value5, 10));
$this->cache->tags(['database', 2016])->put("key6", $value6, 10));
$this->cache->tags(['database', 2017])->put("key7", $value7, 10));
$this->cache->tags(['database', 2017])->put("key8", $value8, 10));
```

I want to flush the cache for the tags 2016 & online.

Using this `$this->cache->tags(['online', 2016])->flush();` It will flush everything with **any** of the tags, i.e., either `online` **or** `2016` (in this case key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6).

I want to delete everything including **all** the tags, i.e., **both** `online` and `2016` (in this case only key1 and key2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this took a bit of digging but here's the verdict.

Yes this is *technically* possible (the best kind of possible?)

First of all, the `RedisTaggedCache` (responsible for implementing tagging in redis) stores all tag member keys in a redis set. Here's how to discover where it is and how you can get all keys:

```
function getAllTagKeys($cache,$tags) {
    $tagStore = new TagSet($cache->getStore(),$tags);
    $key = "<prefix>:{$tagStore->getNamespace()}:". RedisTaggedCache::REFERENCE_KEY_STANDARD;//use REFERENCE_KEY_FOREVER if the keys are cached forever or both one after the other to get all of them
    return collect($cache->getRedis()->smembers($key));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
getAllTagKeys($this->cache, ["online"])
    ->insersect(getAllTagKeys($this->cache, ["2016"]))
    ->each(function ($v) {
         $this->cache->getRedis()->del();
     });
```

This looks like a horrible way to do this. Perhaps it's more sensible to make a feature request to Laravel since this looks like it's something they should be exposing?

Comment: Good idea!!
But the intersects does'nt return anything :(
´$this->cache->getRedis()->keys("<cachePrefix if any>:tag:online:*"));´this return only one key, the tag itself.
The value itself are stored like this: laravel:d28ffc9b90d7d6d49050a821df457bc441b7b0b9:key1

Comment: Yes it works!!
If you come near Málaga (spain) I have a cold beer for you!

Answer (score 2):

I think I would make a key to fit the delete ...

```
$this->cache->tags([andKey('online', 2016)])->put("key1", $value1, 10)); 
$this->cache->tags([andKey('online', 2016)])->put("key2", $value2, 10));
    
$this->cache->tags([andKey('online', 2016)])->flush();

helper:
function andKey($a, $b)
{
   return sprintf("%s.%s", $a, $b);  
}
```

Bit more work, but will save loads of headache when cache system is changed.

edit:
As suggested in comments you can add all keys and flush on any 3.

```
$this->cache->tags(['online', '2016', andKey('online', 2016)])->put("key1", $value1, 10)); 
$this->cache->tags(['online', '2016', andKey('online', 2016)])->put("key2", $value2, 10));
   
$this->cache->tags([andKey('online', 2016)])->flush();

helper:
function andKey($a, $b)
{
   return sprintf("combined.%s.%s", $a, $b);  
}
```

Comment: Actually I like this better than the accepted answer, since it is Cache driver agnostic. I would just keep the original tags and add the combination of both tags as a third tag, maybe with a prefix to prevent unwanted collisions. That way you keep the flexibility of being able to flush the `2016` cache for example, if you decide to change that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In *'yourKeyGoesHere'* you can insert a string used as same as a like with a * or insert directly the exactly key.

```
//Get all cached data ... 
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
$a_keys = $redis->keys("*yourKeyGoesHere*");
foreach ($a_keys as $key){
  //Your Action on key ... (Example delete / forget)
  $redis->del($key);
 }
```